# What overhead does EF creation of dbcontext add for an application with for example 30 tables?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have some simple queries I need to do. The queries are for reference data that will populate drop down lists on my web page. Very simple just data from one table and I need a couple of fields.

My application uses EF already however I noticed that when I code this using EF then it creates a DB Context, Mapping tables are added to this and there's perhaps much more that goes on in the background.

Given 30 mapping tables is anyone aware of just how long all of the startup and creation of the db context might take? Would it be quicker to use an alternative and if so what would be best ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the how long part. Benchmark it. It will depend a LOT on your model. If they are as trivial as you say it should be really fast, but you might be surprised. EF will cache the model. So even with complex models. The model building part will be a one time performance hit.

An easy way to benchmark it is to use the `StopWatch`

```
var stopwathch = new Stopwatch();
stopwathch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext()) {}
}
stopwathch.Stop();
```

Comment: Benchmarking: Get miniprofiler From nuget to get an overview while developing.